# How to store every AWS Step Function's execution to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

Is there a way to store every execution to DynamoDB since AWS Step Function's execution will be deleted after a month.

Comment: There is unlikely to be an "out of the box" method for doing this. Do you know a way to access/export the executions? If so, you could then insert them into DynamoDB, or even just store them in S3.

Comment: I don't know how to export the executions @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AWS StepFunctions API to do that. You can get a list of the executions of a state machine with [ListExecutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ListExecutions.html), and get the history of an execution using [GetExecutionHistory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html). You can then store the result of those calls.

Comment: How will I invoke the GetExecutionHistory? I mean where would I place its parameters?

Comment: It depends on how you make the API requests. I would choose one of the programming languages (see bottom of the pages in the links), and write a short program to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add first step in your machine where you get its execution ARN from [context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) and put it to DynamoDB table

The step may look like this:

```
"Put item into DynamoDB": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
  "Parameters": {
    "TableName": "<your-table-name>",
    "Item": {
      "job_id":  { 
        "S.$" : "$$.Execution.Id"
        }     
    }
  },
  "Next": "<next-task>"
}
```